# VHDL IF statement not behaving as expected

Tags: vhdl

The code is implementing an ALU. I've tested individual bits, but as I try to do the if-statement at the end, which is implementing a specific conditional function, it does not work. I'm using xilinx vivado, the most recent version.

```
library ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

architecture part of project is

    signal bit6 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

begin

with S select -- S is a control value of 4 bits
    sum <=   <expression 1> when "0000",
                   <expression 2> when "0001",
                   -- more code here --
                   -- it's not important --
                   -- it works fine --
                   <expression n> when others;

-- X is a 5 bit input below --
if (S = "1100") and (X(4) = '1') then 
    sum <= <expression alpha>;
else
    sum <= <expression beta>;
end if;
```

Bracing the if-condition does not help. I.e., neither:

```
if ( (S = "1100") and (X(4) = '1') ) then
```

Similarly, another if-statement, using elements of a input also throws an error:

```
if  ( X(4) xor Y(4) xor (Z(4) ) then
```

I don't know if I've misunderstood the allowed syntax here, or if there's something else going on that isn't proper.

Comment: Post complete compilable code. But you have two drivers on the signal "sum" : the other one is probably interfering with the "if" statement (which will presumably be in a process when you post that compilable version)

Comment: The issue was the process statement. My class vhdl reference didn't mention that if statements must occur in a process statement, so I didn't have it nested within one. Likewise, googling "VHDL if statement syntax" took me to results that didn't mention the process statement requirement either.

Answer (score 1):

In VHDL (and in Verilog, for that matter), an `if` statement can only appear within a `process` (`initial` or `always` block in Verilog).

Outside of a process, you must use the `with` ... `select` like you did before, or the `when` ... `else` syntax.

```
sum <= <expression alpha> when <boolean expression>
  else <expression beta>;
```

Comment: That doesn't explain "not behaving as expected" because it has to get through the compiler to behave at all, and what's posted has clearly never seen a compiler in its life.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I think you're reading too much into "not behaving" -- in the body of the question, the OP says that it "throws an error" and mentions "syntax", so I assume he's talking about a compiler syntax error, which is what I'm trying to explain. Obviously, the question is very badly written as-is.